# Why is downloading the Kubuntu .iso such a horrible user experience?

Tags: kubuntu, downloads, canonical

When I go to ubuntu.com, I click "Get Ubuntu", then I click "Download and Install", then I select my desired option, (Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Edubuntu not being options there, sadly), then the download begins. Possibly one more click than necessary, but not bad.

So with no Kubuntu option, I go to kubuntu.com which redirects to kubuntu.org, I click "Get Kubuntu", then I click "Download Kubuntu", then I select my desired version... which takes me to "metrocast.net", where the options at the top of the page are all Ubuntu, not Kubuntu!

So I had to scroll down and click on Kubuntu, where once again I have to select the version I want, new page load and I have to select 32 or 64 bit, and finally at long last my download begins. This is just a flat-out wretched user experience for a "Canonical supported" version of Ubuntu.

Comment: I feel this question a bit harsh for canonical.

Answer (score 2):

just go to http://releases.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/11.10/

On http://releases.ubuntu.com/ you will find all supported releases.

Comment: I would consider this a good answer if there was any way for a user to get to this page from somewhere other than this thread... There is no link to it from either the official Ubuntu or Kubuntu websites.

Comment: If you go to "get ubuntu" -> Alternative downloads you will find links to http://releases.ubuntu.com/{current}/.... I agree it should be easier to find. Fortunately releases.ubuntu.com it's quite easy to remember.

Answer (score 1):

When I visit Kubuntu.com, I am transparently forwarded to kubuntu.org, as you point out. Then I click Download, which forwards me to a page with some information that I should read before I start downloading, such as known issues. I then click on the download button and go the next page where I can choose different ways to download and then to the page where I choose type. I click Begin Download, and it begins.

They could probably have restructured the pages a little bit to collect data on one page... But I don't agree that it is a horrible user experience. Try to download Windows 7 from Microsoft.com and OS X from Apple.com and compare. I just did. Interesting.

The fact that Ubuntu is insanely cool and user friendly at all times, doesn't mean everything else is horrible. It just means it's not quite as cool. :)

Comment: +1 for the answer. Yes, It is not such a bad experience to download Kubuntu

Answer (score 1):

For me the process doesn't involve any third party websites... interesting. And it isn't any harder than downloading the Ubuntu image. Perhaps the reason you have to go through so much hassle is because of your location or something, but this is all I have to do:
Try:

1. Go to kubuntu.org
2. Click the large featured blue "Download" button
3. Click the banner that says "Download" (They have a short reading about Kubuntu so that users don't rush in blindly)
4. Under "Regular download" is your options.

Comment: I think this way needs to be a bit more obvious.  I have never downloaded Kubuntu this and was the 1st time I've heard of it.  Maybe the Download button would just go to the download and select your version instead of a page w/ a lot of text I would have to read